# How to check my page is from 302 redirect?

Tags: redirect

I found that anybody show their page to user, then 302 redirect to my site,
I want stop it.

I thought there would be referer in request header, but didn't!
I tested this in chrome72.0.3626.121 and ie11, and use fiddler to catch Request,
there have no referer header in all request.
And my server side code can't see referer too.

How can I stop 302 redirect to my site??

Answer (score 1):

It's possible these days for sites to disable adding a referrer when a user follows a link. This is a privacy feature.

The result of sites using this feature is that you can't tell if:

A) A user opened your site directly from the addressbar
B) A user came to your site from somewhere else.

If you could tell the difference, it means the privacy feature is not working. Your only option is to block anyone with *no* referrer header, but then you might block a lot of other users as well.

There is one other common reason for this though, if you are running an insecure (`http`) site and you are being linked from secure (`https://`) site. It might be possible to get the referrer back in this case by upgrading your site to `https`.

Comment: I made a qrcode to my user, but somebody made their qrcode, and 302 to my url... crying.

Comment: Then it's blocked on purpose. Instead of trying to get the referrer back, maybe try to think about why this is problematic... is there another way to fix it?

Comment: em, I notified pm, use another way to fix it, like hightlight our logo, anyway, thank you.